# How CMake automatically detects header dependencies

Tags: cmake

I wonder how CMake automatically detects that `main.cpp` depends on `header.h`

```cpp
// header.h
int f() {
  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "header.h"

int main() {
  return f();
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Cppref)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run `cmake . -B build` it creates the following make target in `./build/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make`

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: CMakeFiles/main.dir/compiler_depend.ts
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --progress-dir=/home/nikolay/Cpp/Train/Cppref/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1) "Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o"
    /usr/bin/c++ $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_INCLUDES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/nikolay/Cpp/Train/Cppref/main.cpp
```

Pay attention to the -MD compiler option, as
it is [used to dump dependencies visible to the preprocessor](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_chr1384783682889.htm).

So after the first build it will create `./build/CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d` with the following content

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: /home/nikolay/Cpp/Train/Cppref/main.cpp \
  /home/nikolay/Cpp/Train/Cppref/header.h
```

So whenever you change `header.h`, the target `main.o` will be rebuilt.

Comment: Then how is this generated `main.cpp.o.d` used by Make?

Comment: I think it is used in a direct way. You can see the rules for tagret `main.cpp.o`, which I think is used to generate `main.cpp.o` and hence final executable `main.out`.